# Angular component-only-hooks - works also for directives?

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm using angular 4.2.3 and by looking at the [Docs](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks) which state :

> A directive has the same set of lifecycle hooks, minus the hooks that
>   are specific to component content and views.

The hooks that are specific to a componenet only are :

`ngAfterContentInit` , `ngAfterContentChecked` ,`ngAfterViewInit` , `ngAfterViewChecked`.

But I've created a test  :

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[simpleTimer]'   

})
export class SimpleTimer {

  ngAfterContentInit()  {console.log('directive ngAfterContentInit');}
  ngAfterContentChecked()   {console.log('directive ngAfterContentChecked');  }
  ngAfterViewInit()   {console.log('directive ngAfterViewInit');  }
  ngAfterViewChecked(){console.log('directive ngAfterViewChecked');  }
}
```

Where my main app is :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>Hello
      <div   simpleTimer >

      </div>
    </div>`
})
```

And still  I see in the console :

[image]

**Question**

According to the docs , those hooks should not be emitted for directives. So ?

[**PLNKR**](https://plnkr.co/edit/AzhRe6bjnuPLKJWEJGwp?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its just wrong docs. Those lifecycle hooks fire regularily for directives also. Wouldn't make too much sense otherwise.

Ref: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10221

Comment: What's going on out there with the NG doc team ?

Comment: God knows. There seems to be some general problem with docs. Some (important) things not even being documented, some being wrong...hard to understand but it is what it is.

Comment: I guess they had to write it quickly becuase React was catching them pretty quickly ( by the time until ver 2 officially came out).. so they had to do something official pretty quick

Comment: possibly but then its hard to explain why haven't they fixed it since as that was not yesterday :). just hard to understand.

Comment: Don't you know the rule ? temporarily becomes permanent. too bad.

Comment: that's so true.